# Creative writing in intentionally archaic language: parallelism in abnormal contractions

Tags: contractions, poetry, parallelism, rules

I hope this is on topic here.

I am revising an original poem. No, I am not posting it or asking for a critique. I am intentionally using old-fashioned language. I would like to know if the concept of parallelism applies to 'abnormal' contractions (i.e. words contracted for rhythmic purposes).

A certain line could be written:

*Ne'er woven before*

or: *Ne'er wov'n here before*

Do guidelines exist for such situations? Must I contract *woven* because I contracted a similar word *never*?

Comment: In 'old-fashioned language' spelling and grammar were entirely optional,  especially when it comes to poetry.  Goe forth and multiplie say I.  P.S. Never pass up on the opportunity to use `'ere`!

Comment: But when rhyming 'ere, do remember that the 'ere in «over 'ere» does not rhyme with «'ere he came». Nor do «'ere 'e comes» and «'ere he comes».

Comment: Where is the parallel in removing a 'v' and removing an 'e'?

Comment: Shakespeare contracted or did not contract words depending on what made the poem scan. (He spelled *murderous* as *murtherous* and *murdrous* depending on whether he wanted it to be two or three syllables.) There's absolutely no reason to be consistent about using contractions in your poem.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I mean the words are similar, they both end with 've*x*'. I suppose I could say *wo'en* but *wov'n* seems more natural to me.

Comment: I don't think anybody has ever said *wo'en* (unlike *o'er* which was a very common poetic contraction in earlier days). Use *wov'n*.

Comment: This is not strictly about usage.  But if you are using a contraction for metric reasons, be careful.  Not all contractions save a syllable in the way you hope.  Yours is a case in point.  You are working on an iambic rhythm.  But “wók’n there” does not reduce from 3 syllables to 2.  Say it  and you will hear three syllables.  You would need a word beginning with something like a vowel to get rid of the second syllable of “woken”.

Comment: @Tuffy It is dactylic, not iambic, although it might be difficult to ascertain that from one line. I ended up using *Ne'er wov'n 'ere before* (*'ere* meaning *here*) because it can be pronounced like *wōv-neer*.

Comment: @Mcah Windsor  OK, that does suppress the syllable (by silencing the the vowel). So that’s a result.  The principle is how it sounds when you say it aloud.  The trouble now is that “‘ere” is understood as a synonym for ‘before’ and is pronounced as in ‘air’ and not ‘ear’.

Comment: @Tuffy Incorrect, the one that means before has no apostrophe. *'ere* = *here*, *ere* = *before*.

Comment: @Micah Windsor  I can only advise in a case like that.  You are right that there is a recognised use, at least in speech of " 'ere" to stand for "here".  This will tend to occur in dialects where aspirate is dropped in ordinary speech:  Cockney is one such and there are many others.  So far as I can discover it is not recognised by any dictionary.  So you have to hope that your reader with either instantly recognise the intended word rather than have to stop to work it out.  You can decide whether the risk is worth taking.  The risk is yours.

Answer (score 1):

The only guidelines I know of for such things are the collected works of John Ronald Reuel Tolkien and Clive Staples Lewis (both were professors in English, one specialising in Anglo-Saxon and the other in Mediæval & Renaissance ~).

I'm half joking, but those are fairly well known and much of their work is available online or to be found in charity / second-hand bookshops here.

Otherwise, imitation is the sincerest form of flattery, and reading a lot of examples from the period you have in mind is probably the best you can do.